# Change multiple monitors location gnome shell

Tags: gnome3, desktop-environment, multi-monitor

I connect my laptop to my PC monitor and I use multiple screens with the laptop screen as the primary one.

When I move the mouse to the right of my laptop screen, it goes to my PC monitor and when I move it to the left from my PC monitor, it goes to my laptop screen.

How can I change this to be so that when I move the mouse up from my laptop screen it goes to my PC monitor, and when I move the mouse down from the PC monitor it goes to my laptop screen in gnome shell?

I know that in kde this is configurable.

I don't mind to have this tied to some script if it needs to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the search bar type displays.
Depending on your version of gnome 3, it will either show two displays that you can drag around to your liking, or it may have a button with "arrange combined displays".

[image]

Sometimes on nvidia cards the display menu won't do anything. I have had that in the past, what you do is search for nvidia and there should be an application called nvidia x server and the second entry in the menu should be for the display configuration. You can use that to drag around the monitors.

[image]

Just drag the monitors so that they are stacked instead of horizontal.

Comment: Thanks! mi displays screen looks different that both screens you've added. I didn't know that I could change the position by draging the screens.